# Removing all zeros from an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have an array of shape [120000, 3] in which only the first 1500 elements are useful and the others are 0.

Here an example

```
[15.0, 14.0, 13.0]
[11.0, 7.0, 8.0]
[4.0, 1.0, 3.0]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

I have to find a way to remove all the elements that are [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]. I tried to write this but it doesn't work

```
for point in points:
        if point[0] == 0.0 and point[1] == 0.0 and point[2] == 0.0:
            np.delete(points, point)
```

---

**edit**

All the solutions in the comment work, but I gave the green tick to the one I have used. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few related approaches, split into two camps. You can either use a vectorised approach via calculation of a single Boolean array and [`np.ndarray.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.all.html). Or you can calculate the index of the first row which contains only `0` elements, either via a `for` loop or `next` with a generator expression.

For performance, I recommend you use [`numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/) with a manual `for` loop. Here's one example, but see benchmarking below for a more efficient variant:

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def trim_enum_nb(A):
    for idx in range(A.shape[0]):
        if (A[idx]==0).all():
            break
    return A[:idx]
```

#### Performance benchmarking

```
# python 3.6.5, numpy 1.14.3

%timeit trim_enum_loop(A)     # 9.09 ms
%timeit trim_enum_nb(A)       # 193 µs
%timeit trim_enum_nb2(A)      # 2.2 µs
%timeit trim_enum_gen(A)      # 8.89 ms
%timeit trim_vect(A)          # 3.09 ms
%timeit trim_searchsorted(A)  # 7.67 µs
```

---

#### Test code

**Setup**

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

np.random.seed(0)

n = 120000
k = 1500

A = np.random.randint(1, 10, (n, 3))
A[k:, :] = 0
```

**Functions**

```
def trim_enum_loop(A):
    for idx, row in enumerate(A):
        if (row==0).all():
            break
    return A[:idx]

@jit(nopython=True)
def trim_enum_nb(A):
    for idx in range(A.shape[0]):
        if (A[idx]==0).all():
            break
    return A[:idx]

@jit(nopython=True)
def trim_enum_nb2(A):
    for idx in range(A.shape[0]):
        res = False
        for col in range(A.shape[1]):
            res |= A[idx, col]
            if res:
                break
            return A[:idx]

def trim_enum_gen(A):
    idx = next(idx for idx, row in enumerate(A) if (row==0).all())
    return A[:idx]

def trim_vect(A):
    idx = np.where((A == 0).all(1))[0][0]
    return A[:idx]

def trim_searchsorted(A):
    B = np.frombuffer(A, 'S12')
    idx = A.shape[0] - np.searchsorted(B[::-1], B[-1:], 'right')[0]
    return A[:idx]
```

**Checks**

```
# check all results are the same
assert (trim_vect(A) == trim_enum_loop(A)).all()
assert (trim_vect(A) == trim_enum_nb(A)).all()
assert (trim_vect(A) == trim_enum_nb2(A)).all()
assert (trim_vect(A) == trim_enum_gen(A)).all()
assert (trim_vect(A) == trim_searchsorted(A)).all()
```

Comment: Could you explain to me the if in the trim_enum_gen? What is the .all()?

Comment: See [`np.ndarray.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.all.html), [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) and [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions). If you have a **specific** question on how they are used here, I can try and explain further.

Comment: numba for numba : replacing `if (A[idx]==0).all():` by         ` for j in range(3):\
            if v[j]!=0:\
                break\
        if v[j]==0:\
            break  is four times faster ;)

Comment: @B.M., Good point, updated. It takes a while to get used to *trying* to write nested loops. The solution I now have seems to be ~100x faster than previous numba!

Answer (score 8):

Don't use for loops--those are slow.  Calling `np.delete` repeatedly in a for loop is a recipe for poor performance.

Instead, create a mask:

```
zero_rows = (points == 0).all(1)
```

That is an array of length 120000 which is True where all the elements in that row are 0.

Then find the first such row:

```
first_invalid = np.where(zero_rows)[0][0]
```

Finally, slice the array:

```
points[:first_invalid]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = [[15.0, 14.0, 13.0],
[11.0, 7.0, 8.0],
[4.0, 1.0, 3.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

The simple iterative solution:

```
y = [i for i in x if i != [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

A better solution (Python 3.x):

```
y = list(filter(lambda a: a != [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], x))
```

output:

```
[[15.0, 14.0, 13.0], [11.0, 7.0, 8.0], [4.0, 1.0, 3.0]]
```

Comment: Would be interesting how this compares to John Zwinck's answer regarding performance.

Comment: Why is you (Python 3.x) solution better (and why doesn't it work just as well in Python 2)?

Answer (score 2):

know it is over just thought i would give my answer :)

```
x = [[15.0, 14.0, 13.0],
[11.0, 7.0, 8.0],
[4.0, 1.0, 3.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

then a simeple list comprehension can be made

```
[i for i in x if all(i)]
```

and outputs:

```
[[15.0, 14.0, 13.0],[11.0, 7.0, 8.0],[4.0, 1.0, 3.0]]
```

takes

```
0.0000010866 # seconds or 1.0866 microseconds
```

take the time with a gram of salt it is really inconsisten give my 2 sec to get a better estimation

when:

```
x = [[15.0, 14.0, 13.0],
[11.0, 7.0, 8.0],
[4.0, 1.0, 3.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]*(120000//7)
```

i get the time to

```
0.01199 # seconds
```

this time is hugely based on wather they are 0 or not, 0 are way faster since it is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

For logarithmic complexity, you can use [numpy.searchsorted](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) after casting data by rows:

```
B=np.frombuffer(A,'S12')
index=B.size-np.searchsorted(B[::-1],B[-1:],'right')[0]
```

`index` will be the number of not null items if the first ones are all not null.

test :

```
>>>> %timeit B.size-searchsorted(B[::-1],B[-1:],'right')[0]
2.2 µs
```

Comment: I think you need `A.shape[0]-np.searchsorted(B[::-1],B[-1:],'right')[0]`.

Comment: Nice solution anyway +1, I also added this solution to my post timings, hope that's ok with you.

Answer (score 1):

A simple iterative solution with usage of [vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)

```
import numpy as np
b = np.empty((0,3), float)
for elem in a:
    toRemove = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
    if(not np.array_equal(elem,toRemove)):
        b=np.vstack((b, elem))
```